# Can't save a file in a folder I created. (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, save, directory

I've created a folder using the following code:

```
def _infrastructure(self):
    lib = "data"
    try:
        os.makedirs(lib)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EXIST:
            raise
```

And I want to save a file I'm creating using this code:

```
def save(self, dic):
    filename = "file.csv"           
    my_path = "data"
    filepath = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), my_path, filename)
    self.curr = csv.writer(open(filepath, "w"))            

    for key, val in self.dic.items():
        self.curr.writerow([key, val])
```

What I want to do is to save the file I've created in the folder that I've also created and it looks like the issue here is in the for loop, because all my variables do get the parameters.

Comment: What exception are you seeing?

Comment: are you sure that `data` is in `~` when running your first snippet?

Comment: There's no exception, it just doesn't save the file in this folder (or anywhere)

Comment: maybe you should close the file...

Comment: There is an exception now, it says:
`Traceback (most recent call last):

    self.curr = csv.writer(open(filepath, "w"))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\data\\file.csv'`